# Laravel create tables with same column names

Tags: php, database, laravel

I try to create 2 tables:

```
Products
- name
- description
- price
- source
- processing_started_at
- processing_ended_at
```

and

```
Orders
- customer_id
- order_lines_id
- source
- processing_started_at
- processing_ended_at
```

As you can see both tables has the columns: **source, processing_started_at** and **processing_ended_at**

In the future i would like to create more tables with the same column names and maybe i would create more columns that all the tables need.

So i wonder what the best approach is to keep things a bit clean. Is there a way to create some sort of default columns whenever i create a new migration file? or should i just create a relationship? I have also found something about polymorphic relationship but im not sure if it is meant for this

Comment: A relationship is between both your migrations table.

Comment: I would rather use morph. Please [check this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations) example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you go for polymorphic relations if you have not more complex dependencies are in their table. Create one table with:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('processes', function (BlueprintCustom $table) {
        $table->morphs('process');
        $this->timestamp('processing_started_at')->nullable();
        $this->timestamp('processing_ended_at')->nullable();
    });
}
```

And add your relation to your relevant model. This will relief from the same field to your migration.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom Blueprint class that inherits from

```
Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint
```

something like this:

```
namespace App\Whatever;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class BlueprintCustom extends Blueprint {
    public function customfields()
    {
        $this->string('source')->nullable();
        $this->timestamp('processing_started_at')->nullable();
        $this->timestamp('processing_ended_at')->nullable();
    }
}
```

So then, when migrating, you could do something like:

```
use App\Whatever\BlueprintCustom;

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('newtable', function (BlueprintCustom $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('blah');
        $table->customfields();  //This adds your fields
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: if 10 tables are using customfields(), how would you add more custom fields in future? migration all 10 tables? and if I add a 11th table, how do I ensure it gets all the custom fields?